# Could not load file or assembly not resolved

Tags: .net

The Exception is

> Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=2.5.1.827, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The version of 'Autofac' dll that is added to project is 2.5.1.827.But still getting above error.

Comment: More info please.  What are you trying to do when you get this error?

Comment: Have you checked if the dll is located in multiple places? For example in the GAC?

Answer (score 2):

Enable Fusion logging to assist in seeing which Assemblies are being loaded.  You can find many articles and blogs on doing this:

[How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/06/02/debugging-load-problems-using-fusion-log.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as you.  My PC shut down unexpectedly and after rebooting I ran into this error when running my application.  I was using using Autofac in a ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I cleared my `temporary ASP.NET files` (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files) and restart IIS and everything was cool.

Answer (score 0):

May be you add Autofac.Contrib assembly that reference to different version of Castle.Core

I faced with this issue when add reference to AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2, this assembly reference to old version of Castle.Core while I add newest version of Castle.Core.

I solved it by copy code of AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2 to my solution (just 2 files) and it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime,all Dlls are not copied into some specific bin folder.See the warning and add the required Dlls in the specific folder which are described in warnings.